# Pure Dimension of a Intersection Variety (from Mumford's Red Book)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

My question refers to an argument from D. Mumford's "Red Book of Schemes" (page 211):

[image]

By definition: A subvariety $Z \subset X$ has ***pure*** dimension $r$ iff ***every*** component of $Z$ has dimension $r$.

Futhermore if $X$ is a scheme then the dimension $dim(X)$ equals the ***supremum*** of the dimensions of all irreducible components of $X$.

We know by §7 Thm 2 (page 41) that $V_i:= V(t_i)$ are of pure dimension $n-1$

My question is why is the intersection $V_1 \cap V_2 $ pure $(n-2)$-dimensional?

Why it cannot occure that $V_1 \cap V_2 $ has components of lower dimension than $n-2$?

Comment: In Mumford's book you'll find the following claim: Let $X$ be a nonsingular variety and let $V,W⊂X$ be closed subvarieties with $\text{dim}(V)=r$ and $\text{dim}(W)=s$. If $V \cap W \neq \emptyset$, then every irreducible component $Z$ of $V∩W$ has dimension $≥r+s−\text{dim}(X)$. And I think in the proof we are working in a nonsingular setting, though I am not sure.

Comment: I'm not sure why it suffice here to work with non singular variety, since I don't see an argument that factorial implies non singular (of on ring level: factorial in general not imply regular) or do I oversee something?

Comment: @ParthivBasu: could you tell me the number of the lemma/thm which you quoted. I looked up several times in the book but unfortunately haven't found it.

Comment: I should have been more specific. It's on page 187 of the **The Red Book of Varieties and Schemes, Second, Expanded Edition** (https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b62130).  Also see The Stacks project **Proper Intersections** (https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AZL). You are right, factorial does not imply singular. But I think, though I am not sure, in the proof you are working in a nonsingular setting (the complement of the singular locus).

Comment: Typo: imply nonsingular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nothing but Krull's principal ideal theorem. Pick an affine neighborhood $\operatorname{Spec} R$ of $x'$. Then $R/(t_1)$ is the coordinate ring of $V_1$ in this neighborhood, and $V_1\cap V_2$ is given by $V(t_2)\subset \operatorname{Spec} R/(t_1)$. The irreducible components of $V_1\cap V_2$ are then the minimal primes over $(t_2)\subset R/(t_1)$. By Krull's principal ideal theorem, these are of height at most one, so combining this with the assumption that $V(t_1)$ and $V(t_2)$ don't share any components, the irreducible components of $V(t_2)\subset \operatorname{Spec} R/(t_1)$ are of codimension one, or $V_1\cap V_2$ is of pure codimension two.